# getView from Custom Adapter not updating the list items

Tags: android, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am working on a WordList Builder app in android. The app picks up words from the database and displays them.  There is also a Favourites tab for displaying only the favourites. The main page displays all the words and shows a Star near the favourite words. When a user unselects a word from the favourites tab, and moves back to the main page, the star still shows on the unselected favourite word. However the data picked up from the database clearly shows the update. I then added log statements to the getView method of the custom adapter, and here the item list still shows the initially loaded word list. It doesnt update.

Below is my code for the custom adapter:

```
public class WordListAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    protected static final String LOG_TAG = WordListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<Word> items;
    int layoutResourceId;
    private Context context;

    public WordListAdapter(Context context,int layoutResourceId,ArrayList <Word> items) {
        super(context,layoutResourceId,items);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("WordListAdapter" ," NotifyDataSetChanged is called items size = " + this.items.size());
    }

    public void refreshList(ArrayList<Word> items) {
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        Log.i("WordListAdapter; " , " getView item size =" + this.items.size());
        Word wordListItems = this.items.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wordlist_item, null);

        }

        TextView tvWordName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.wordlist_word);
        tvWordName.setText(wordListItems.getWordName());
        TextView tvWordId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.wordlist_id);
        tvWordId.setText(Integer.toString(wordListItems.getId()));
        CheckBox cbFav = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxFav);
        Log.i("WordListAdapter :" , "Position= " + position + "  Word " + wordListItems);
        cbFav.setChecked(wordListItems.isFavourite());
        cbFav.setTag(position);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the main Activity:

```
public class WordBuilder extends Activity {

    //private static SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = null;
    private static WordListAdapter wordListAdapter = null;
    private static ListView lv = null;
    private static WordListDBSupport dbSupport = null;
    TabBar tabbar;
    ArrayList<Word> wordList;
    Intent intent ;

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            long viewId = view.getId();
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wordlist_id);
            int rowId = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());


            Log.i("RowId : ", String.format("%d", rowId));

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("rowId", rowId);
            tabbar.getIntent().putExtra("rowId", rowId);
            switchTabInActivity(tabbar.WORDLISTDETAILACTIVITY_TAB);


        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("WordBuilder ", " onCreate() ");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        intent = getIntent();

        tabbar = (TabBar) this.getParent();


        dbSupport = new WordListDBSupport(this);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordlist);

        //If getting tab 3, only the favourites
        wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();

        wordListAdapter = new WordListAdapter(this,R.id.wordlist, wordList);
        lv.setAdapter(wordListAdapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemClick);


    }

    public void switchTabInActivity(int indexTabToSwitchTo){
        tabbar.switchTab(indexTabToSwitchTo);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("WordBuilder ", " onResume() ");
        updateCursorAdapter();
    }


    public void updateCursorAdapter() {
        //Query to get the updated list
        wordList.clear();
        Log.i("WordBuilder ", " updateCursorAdapter() wordList size =  " + wordList.size());
        wordList = dbSupport.getAllWords(intent.getIntExtra("isfavourite",0));
        Log.i("WordBuilder", "wordlist size after = " +wordList.size() );

        wordListAdapter.refreshList(wordList);
    }

    public void saveFavouritesHandler(View view) {

        //To be called on check or uncheck of the checkbox
        int position = (Integer)view.getTag();
        CheckBox cbFav = (CheckBox)view;
        Word wordToUpdate = wordList.get(position);
        int rowId = wordToUpdate.getId();
        Log.i("RowId isFav: ", String.format("%d ", rowId) + " isfav " + cbFav.isChecked() + " wordname= " + wordToUpdate.getWordName() + " Position = " + position);
        if (cbFav.isChecked()) {
            //save the selection in the database
            dbSupport.updateFavourite(rowId,1);
        } else {
            dbSupport.updateFavourite(rowId,0);
            Log.i("WordBuilder :" , " Position bring removed =" + position );
            if(intent.getIntExtra("isfavourite",0) == 1) {
                wordList.remove(position);
            }
        }
        updateCursorAdapter();
    }



}
```

I removed battle from the favourites list and updated the database.
However when i go back to the main tab, which lists all the words, battle is still listed as a favourite.

[image: all words showing old list data with battle highlighted]

[image: favourite list showing only 3 items]

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the ListView adapter when yiu add or remove the fav icon. if the they are 2 different activities , you have to update the aapter in onResume of mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

Try Calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
When u want to refresh the list.
Hope it helps